# OperationalError in Django Migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-database

First I created a Model named '`userorders`' having fields : `id`(by default), `user_id`, and `order_id`.

Then after realizing I don't need `order_id`, I deleted it from MySQL DB first (using Workbench),
then I made changes in the model in Django, but it keeps showing errors now.

**0013_orderdetails_userorders.py**

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='userorders',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('user_id', models.IntegerField()),
                ('order_id', models.IntegerField()),
            ],
        ),
```

**0014_remove_userorders_order_id.py**

```
dependencies = [
        ('shoppingCart', '0013_orderdetails_userorders'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='userorders',
            name='order_id',
        ),
    ]
```

**0015_userorders_order_id.py**

```
dependencies = [
    ('shoppingCart', '0014_remove_userorders_order_id'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='userorders',
        name='order_id',
        field=models.IntegerField(default=None),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
```

**0016_remove_userorders_order_id.py**

```
dependencies = [
        ('shoppingCart', '0015_userorders_order_id'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='userorders',
            name='order_id',
        ),
    ]
```

**0017_auto_20200508_1639.py**

```
dependencies = [
    ('shoppingCart', '0016_remove_userorders_order_id'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='orderdetails',
        old_name='user_id',
        new_name='order_id',
    ),
]
```

**ERRORS** - when I try to make migrations for any changes I do (Changes are not reflected in DB)

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'order_id'; check that column/key exists")
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'order_id'; check that column/key exists")
```

Currently, `userorders` contains 2 fields- `id` and `user_id`

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your workflow you should have removed the field, made the migration and applied the migration to your DB.

But since you now have the issue, you might be able to solve it with recreating the column `order_id` in the table (with workbench) and then do `makemigrations` & `migrate` then django can drop the column and shouldn't show the error.

Comment: After this, it now shows a new error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'user_id' in 'shoppingcart_orderdetails'")` 
But no such field exists in that table. I've tried making one in DB, which leads to `Duplicate Column Name`. Can u help?

Comment: did you create the migrations by hand or with the `makemigrations` command? It looks like django tries to apply migrations but your DB is not "in sync" / looks different as django expects...

Comment: ok just to clarify  know you are stuck at `0017_auto_20200508_1639.py` correct? and you have a column `user_id` in the table `shoppingcart_orderdetails` ?